# Union type doesn't work with conflicting properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm trying to combine some components in a React Native app I'm building so they can share logic and styling and make it easier to maintain them. Right now, the only difference between all of them is what interface they extend for props and the name of the component that's rendered. In its simplified form, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
interface ISharedInputProps {
    label: string;
    errorText?: string | null;
    isPassword?: boolean;
    hasTextRight?: boolean;
}

export interface IInputProps extends React.ComponentProps<typeof TextInput>, ISharedInputProps {
    inputType: 'input';
}

export interface IMaskedInputProps extends React.ComponentProps<typeof MaskedTextInput>, ISharedInputProps {
    inputType: 'masked';
}

export interface ICurrencyInputProps extends React.ComponentProps<typeof CurrencyInput>, ISharedInputProps {
    inputType: 'currency';
}

const Input: React.FC<IInputProps | IMaskedInputProps | ICurrencyInputProps> = ({
    inputType,
    ...props
}) => {
    // Component logic here
    return (
        // Shared wrapping UI here
        { inputType === 'input' && <TextInput {...props}/> }
        { inputType === 'masked' && <MaskedTextInput {...props}/> }
        { inputType === 'currency' && <CurrencyInput {...props}/> }
        // Shared wrapping UI here
    )
};

export default Input;
```

However, as soon as I get to the inputType conditionals, the compiler throws an error because there are conflicts between each type not having compatible values (ie: "Type '(text: string, rawText: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(text: string) => void'". The actual union type on the declaration of the Input component seems to not throw an error, it's just when initializing the inner component. Removing either IMaskedInputProps or ICurrencyInputProps works, so the conflicts seem to be happening between them.

My understanding was that if I used the inputType set as a predefined value (ie: 'input'), it would automatically assign the IMaskedInputProps interface to the component, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to do what I want without just changing the Input type to `React.FC<any>` and putting a bunch of checks in the UI itself?

Comment: `inputType` for `CurrencyInput` should be `currency` right? You have it set to `input`.

Comment: @JeffMercado ah, whoops, my bad. Fixed! It's right on the app :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the destructuring assignment and just have:

```
const Input: React.FC<IInputProps | IMaskedInputProps | ICurrencyInputProps> = (props) => {
    // Component logic here
    return (
        // Shared wrapping UI here
        { props.inputType === 'input' && <TextInput {...props}/> }
        { props.inputType === 'masked' && <MaskedTextInput {...props}/> }
        { props.inputType === 'currency' && <CurrencyInput {...props}/> }
        // Shared wrapping UI here
    )
};
```

When you destructure `inputType` from the props object you are creating a brand new variable with the type `'input' | 'masked' | 'currency'`. TS will not remember that this is the same property from the discriminated union of objects. If you had another local variable typed the same way with a different value you would not expect to be able to discriminate props with it because it has no relationship to the object.

Comment: Interesting! Referencing it as props.inputType seems to work. Well, at least that was easier than I thought it'd be!